# Install Grub without Linux

Tags: grub2, 64-bit, windows-7, 32-bit

My brother wants to get windows 7 64 bit alongside his Windows 7 32 bit. How can I install/modify Grub onto his computer in order to create easy boot options without having to install a Linux Distribution. I know this isn't really a Linux question and I’m sorry about the off topic, but this website will probably give me the best answers to grub.

Comment: I'm not certain but you may be able to run Boot-Repair. But the only way I know how to do so is from a live CD or USB. And it should work fine without an option to boot into Linux. Check it out here if you want to give it a try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Take a look at the following links: http://superuser.com/questions/127509/install-grub-bootloader-without-installing-linux, http://atagunov.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-grub2-without-linux.html

Comment: @WeylinSchreck or use... [SuperGrubDisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk). TADA!!

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with ubuntu. The Grub page is at http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/

Comment: Can we not just "demonize" questions that are relatively off topic? The person came here for help, can we at least try to help them if someone has the knowledge and wants to give them the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has its own bootloader that will allow you to choose between installed versions of windows running on different partitions.

Comment: +1 Good point, but please argument why are you deviating from what the OP's asked. Example: `You don't need to install GRUB, because...`

Comment: grub is more advanced